# Merge two file by sorting them based by timestamp using three threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, trading

I have two file: A,B with rows as csv:timestamp, parameters.. I want to read from one thread one file and from another thread the other file and compare the timestamps in a third thread.
The goal is to construct a vector with the content of the row sorted with the timestamp of both file.
How would you approach this problem?
I did something like this: but it doesn't print out all the timestampsand maybe I'm missing something:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
long long timestamp1, timestamp2;
std::vector<long long> timestamps;
bool finished1 = false, finished2 = false;


void thread2() {
  std::ifstream file2("a.csv");
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(file2, line)) {
    std::vector<std::string> values = split(line, ',');
    long long current_timestamp = std::stoll(values[4]);
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
      while (timestamp1 >= current_timestamp) {
        cv.wait(lock);
      }
      timestamp2 = current_timestamp;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    finished2 = true;
  }
  cv.notify_one();
}

void thread3() {
  while (!finished1 || !finished2) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    cv.wait(lock);
    if (finished1 && finished2) {
      break;
    }
    if (timestamp1 >= timestamp2) {
      timestamps.push_back(timestamp1);
      std::cout << timestamp1 <<"\n" << std::flush;
    } else {
      timestamps.push_back(timestamp2);
        std::cout << timestamp2 <<"\n" << std::flush;
    }
  }
}
#include <algorithm>


int main() {
  std::thread t1(thread1);
  std::thread t2(thread2);
  std::thread t3(thread3);

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();

  std::cout << std::is_sorted(timestamps.begin(),timestamps.end());



}
```

Comment: Can you explain the perceived benefit of reading files in separate threads? The jumble of interdependent state does not seem to be helping you with anything. Or is this homework?

Comment: At the end I want a vector of all the time stamp, if I store them reading from file one, and then store file two, and then compare the results I’m basically going to read the data 2 times, like this I’m reading them just one time. Am I wrong?

Comment: At the moment you have two threads taking turns (so one is always blocked), a third thread that just waits for the first two to finish, and a fourth thread that starts three threads (of which only one can proceed at any time) and then waits for them all. It's like a maximally pessimal version of coroutines.

Comment: And how would I approach it? Read one file into a sorted container. Read the second file likewise. Then use `std::merge`. **IF** this is too slow, or the files are too big, then consider optimizing it.

Comment: Mmm you are right.. and how would you do this in order to be more efficient? Because my data in the file A are something around 100million row and is going to take forever if I read it two times…

Comment: Why would you read the same file two times? Read one file into memory. Read the second file into memory. Unless your files are much bigger than you suggest or you're running this on a pocket calculator, it shouldn't be a problem. At least _do_ the simplest possible thing first and see if it really _is_ a problem, rather than inventing complex solutions to imaginary barriers.

Comment: How much data is it total? In particular, will it all fit in memory or not?

Comment: @Useless: Just OOC, why bother to read them into separate sorted containers? Seems like `std::merge` could work with ` std::istream_iterator` to treat the file objects as iterables of lines, passing a comparator (to parse/compare the timestamps), and directly construct the sorted `vector` without the temporaries, and no meaningful additional complexity.

Comment: One file is around 5/6 Gb..  so it’s pretty big and I’ll have to store it in the heap

Comment: If you're using a machine where that is an actual problem, then it's relevant information you should edit into the question. @ShadowRanger - I chose not to assume the input files are sorted, since OP hasn't chosen to tell us anything about them.

Answer (score 1):

The race condition, that result in loss of data, is due to a common misconception that assumes that notifying a condition variable results in an immediate wakeup of any thread that's listening on the condition variable, instantly. Additionally, it's also expected that the woken execution thread is guaranteed to immediately execute all of its assigned tasks, instantly, before it gets blocked on a mutex or a condition variable, again.

This is not the case.

All that `notify_one()` guarantees is that any execution thread that's listening on the condition variable ***will*** be woken up at some point after `notify_one()` is entered, which may be ***before or after*** `notify_one()` returns. ***That's it***.

So, with that in mind, let's take a look at the sequence of events in `thread1` (indentation adjusted):

```
       timestamp1 = current_timestamp;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
```

`timestamp1` is updated. The mutex is unlocked. The condition variable is notified.

`thread3` is now scheduled to be woken up. But you have no guarantees, whatsoever, that not only did it wake up but it also managed to successfully relock the mutex. All you have is a nebulous promises from `notify_one` that this will happen. Eventually.

Meanwhile, back at the ranch:

```
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
      while (timestamp2 >= current_timestamp) {
        cv.wait(lock);
      }
      timestamp1 = current_timestamp;
```

`thread1` managed to read the next timestamp and relock the mutex. Modern CPUs are fast. They can accomplish quite a lot before a context switch to another execution thread. This same thread discovers that the `while` condition is still true.

Based on the fact that the logic waits until the shared `current_timestamp` is less than the current value I conclude that the timestamps must be in decreasing order. Well, the last time around the block `timestamp2`, from the other thread was 1000 and `current_timestamp` was 900; now, the next `current_timestamp` is 800. It's still less than 1000, so we proceed on our merry way, updating`current_timestamp` from 900 to 800.

Meanwhile, `thread3` is still having a nice dream, and only now beginning to wake up from its slumber, as a result of the prior `notify_one` (which is now just a distant memory to this execution thread). And `thread3` missed the `900` value completely. It was replaced by 800. It's gone forever, never to be seen again.

This is not the only flaw in the shown code's logic. The missing data you're seeing is not due to some minor, single oversight, just a few lines of code that needs to be fixed. The logic is flawed in several different ways, that results in the missing data that you're seeing. You will need to completely rework the entire logic if you still want to use this multi-threaded approach to the described task.

Comment: Thank you, so what do you suggest?

Comment: So what do you think about his : since the file itself is already ordered by timestamp I can do : 1 thread in which I read from one file and put what I read in a queue, second thread does the same with another queue. Third thread will read the top of both queue and just print out the one with the less time stamp? I’ll use mutex anywhere I use these 2 queue to manage race condition.

Comment: Sure. But this is not really much more than what the shown code tries to do, it's just that the current code uses a queue of one value. Just like with the shown code, the most important factor is to get multithreading logic correct.

Comment: Ok and so what do you think I should do? sorry again

Comment: Just what you're already doing: keep learning and trying to get it right. There is no substitute to taking the time and effort to learn correct multithreaded semantics. Everyone learns by trial and error.